# Rails 3 - request.request_uri in model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, html-lists

exist any way to have in my own function in model the **request.request_uri**?

Now I have in model called Func.rb this:

```
class Func
   def self.url_adr
     request.request_uri
   end
end
```

But I am getting an error **undefined local variable or method `request' for Func:Class**

Comment: you are trying to violate MVC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Please let me know what really want to do, and maybe we find a solution without harming the MCV model of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

The request object is available from controllers.  I suppose you could pass it in as an argument to a model if you must, e.g.

```
##### in controller
Func.url_addr(request)

##### in model
def self.url_adr(controller_request)
  controller_request.request_uri
end
```

However, Ian has a good point, request data is not usually associated with models.